# Cordova Connection to server was Unsuccessful

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

`The Connection to the server was unsuccessful(file:///android-asset/www/index.html)`

is showing when i run my android application.
please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you add some code? like the code in your main activity file. is your index file inside assets directory? like : assets/www/index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Application Error - The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android\_asset/www/index.html)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319809/application-error-the-connection-to-the-server-was-unsuccessful-file-andr)

Answer (score 26):

For latest Cordova (4+) this a setting in `config.xml`:

e.g.

```
<preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="70000"/>
```

Increases default timeout to 70 seconds (default is 20), reducing the chance of timing out.

Docs: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html#preference

> When loading a page, the amount of time to wait before throwing a
>   timeout error.

Comment: This one solved my problem for the latest version of Cordova. Much more simple than other workarounds.

Comment: were to add this tag

Comment: In config.xml, in the root folder of your project

Answer (score 8):

This may asked here many times.. 
This issue can fix by adding a timeout to the webview call (index.html). In your project_name.java class just add this

```
 super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 5000);
```

And in Cordova latest, just use this to timeout

```
 super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 5000);
```

Also go through these so questions

[Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319809/application-error-the-connection-to-the-server-was-unsuccessful-file-andr)

[Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633940/the-connection-to-the-server-was-unsuccessful-file-android-asset-www-index-h)

**UPDATE :**

One more solution, try this

Create a main.html and put your code there, and in your index.html just redirect to main.html

```
<script>
 window.location='./main.html';
</script>
```

Comment: manukv thanks for ur answer but it will not work i am still getting the same error after modified my .java class.please let me know any other solution

Comment: which cordova version are you using and are you trying to run app in emulator or device??
answer updated pls check it

Answer (score 4):

[This blog post](https://www.robertkehoe.com/2013/01/fix-for-phonegap-connection-to-server-was-unsuccessful/) from Robert Kehoe:

- Seemed to be EASY to me
- Made sense to me
- WORKED for me

Rename your index.html to "main.html"

Create a new "index.html" and put the following content into it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>the title</title>
   <script>
     window.location='./main.html';
   </script>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Rebuild your app! No more errors!

**Robert also said**,

> Another good idea is to give your application a “splash screen”, so that the user gets instant feedback that your app is loading/working, before it is fully ready.

Comment: Sadly I don't have cordova and its plugins injected into main.html

Comment: In my case, it's the splash screen that's timing out.  :-(

Answer (score 2):

> The main problem for this issue is take more time to load your page.
>
> yes it's can a hack to solve this issue, make a html page name
>   index.html and your existing index page name to be change as a
>   main.html or any other one give a redirection to this page like this

```
    <script>
       window.location='main.html';
    </script>
```

> am sure it's work very much

Answer (score 0):

hey i think this error may come load multiple script in starting time so it will take more time.

so you set like this in your java...

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 600000);
```

[reference1](https://www.robertkehoe.com/2013/01/fix-for-phonegap-connection-to-server-was-unsuccessful/)
[reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319809/application-error-the-connection-to-the-server-was-unsuccessful-file-andr)